# How can I fix this Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0 error?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am experimenting w/ `UITableView`in Swift 5.

I would like to insert and delete rows.

My table is crashing when adding additional rows. The first insert works OK.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var items = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CELL_ID")

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.addMoreRows([1,2,3,4,5])
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.addMoreRows([6,7,8,9,10])
        }

    }

    private func addMoreRows(_ data: [Int]) {

        self.items.append(contentsOf: data)

        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

        for i in 0...items.count - 1 {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
        }

        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .left)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL_ID", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell #\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (10 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop for creating the array of index paths is incorrect. You want it to iterate over `data.count`, not `items.count`. And you want the new index paths to be based on the previous `items.count`.

```
private func addMoreRows(_ data: [Int]) {
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    for i in data.indices() {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: items.count + i, section: 0))
    }

    self.items.append(contentsOf: data)

    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .left)
}
```

Comment: Oh I like this, I always forget about `indices` - I think I prefer this over my attempt for sure

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to append on `items` after you calculate the `IndexPath` collection.

You should also use a range to support the next iteration.

Try this:

```
private func addMoreRows(_ data: [Int]) {

    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    for i in items.count...items.count + data.count - 1 {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
    }

    self.items.append(contentsOf: data)

    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .left)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `addMoreRows` the index paths start always with 0 so in the second call 10 index paths are created.

A more reliable way is to count the items before and after the insertion

```
private func addMoreRows(_ data: [Int]) {
    let startIndex = self.items.count
    self.items.append(contentsOf: data)
    let endIndex = self.items.count

    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    for i in startIndex..<endIndex {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
    }

    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .left)
}
```